# MobileFirst analytics - capture request/response time

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

For capturing analytics in MobileFirst server, is there any way I can capture the following:

1. Complete round trip time from Mobile app —> Adapter —> API end point —> Adapter —> Mobile app
2. Round trip time from Adapter —> API end point  —> Adapter

Is there any in built metrics for the above two?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the adapter related charts on the Operational Analytics Console > Infrastructure > Server and Network & Adapters